# Solving linear equations during inverse iteration

Tags: opencl, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am using OpenCL to calculate the eigenvectors of a matrix. AMD has an [example](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/samples/Pages/default.aspx) of eigenvalue calculation so I decided to use inverse iteration to get the eigenvectors.

I was following the algorithm described [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node96.html) and I noticed that in order to solve step 4 I need to solve a system of linear equations (or calculate the inverse of a matrix).

[image: Inverse Iteration]

What is the best way to do this on a GPU using OpenCL? Are there any examples/references that I should look into?

---

EDIT: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that my matrix is symmetric tridiagonal. From what I have been reading this could be important and maybe simplifies the whole process a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the matrix is tridiagonal is VERY important - that reduces the complexity of the problem from O(N^3) to O(N). You can probably get some speedup from the fact that it's symmetric too, but that won't be as dramatic.

The method for solving a tridiagonal system is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm.

Also note that you don't need to store all N^2 elements of the matrix, since almost all of them will be zeroes. You just need one vector of length N (for the diagonal) and two of length N-1 for the sub- and superdiagonals. And since your matrix is symmetric, the sub- and superdiagonals are the same.

Hope that's helpful...

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work and it's really simple. I will port it to OpenCL.

Comment: @nmat just wondering if you had any success writing your tridiagonal solver in OpenCL? I also wish to solve a tridiagonal system. At he moment there doesn't seem to be a canonical way of doing linear algebra (BLAS and LAPACK) on the GPU. Since a few years have since asking you question, do you have any suggestions on the best way forward?

Comment: @boyfarrell Sorry, but I can't help you. I didn't start writing it. Good luck with your problem

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition). 
Here's [example](http://www.noctua-blog.com/index.php/2011/04/21/lu-matrix-decomposition-in-parallel-with-cuda/).

It's written in CUDA, but I think, it's not so hard to rewrite it in OpenCL.